# Stringbuilder does not create new instance if the initial capacity set too small but a book says otherwise

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("test", 4);
sb.Append('\n');
sb.AppendLine("test1");
sb.AppendLine("test2");
sb.AppendLine("test3");
sb.AppendLine("test4");
```

looking on IL code there is only one `newobj` line, but I thought there should be more instances of StringBuilder class since it should increase its capacity by creating new object? Or I got it wrong?

```
// [3 1 - 3 49]
    IL_0000: ldstr        "test"
    IL_0005: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0006: newobj       instance void [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(string, int32)
    IL_000b: stloc.0      // sb

    // [4 1 - 4 17]
    IL_000c: ldloc.0      // sb
    IL_000d: ldc.i4.s     10 // 0x0a
    IL_000f: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(char)
    IL_0014: pop

    // [5 1 - 5 24]
    IL_0015: ldloc.0      // sb
    IL_0016: ldstr        "test1"
    IL_001b: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::AppendLine(string)
    IL_0020: pop

    // [6 1 - 6 24]
    IL_0021: ldloc.0      // sb
    IL_0022: ldstr        "test2"
    IL_0027: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::AppendLine(string)
    IL_002c: pop

    // [7 1 - 7 24]
    IL_002d: ldloc.0      // sb
    IL_002e: ldstr        "test3"
    IL_0033: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::AppendLine(string)
    IL_0038: pop

    // [8 1 - 8 24]
    IL_0039: ldloc.0      // sb
    IL_003a: ldstr        "test4"
    IL_003f: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder [System.Runtime]System.Text.StringBuilder::AppendLine(string)
    IL_0044: pop
    IL_0045: ret
```

from Troelsen book about c#, translated paragraph by me: "If you add more characters than the specified limit, the StringBuilder object will copy its data to **a new instance** and increase the buffer size by the specified limit."

Asked a friend to provide original quote, here it is, page 89 "Pro C#10 with .Net 6":

> If you append more characters than the specified limit, the
> StringBuilder object will copy its data into a new instance and grow
> the buffer by the specified limit.

Comment: Very unclear why do you think that the code shown would result in creation of multiple string builder instances. Can you elaborate? (I think it is somewhat safe to completely drop IL part till you figure out why/where you expect new string builder to be create in the C# code). Please [edit] post with that info.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting? What do you mean by "more exemplars of StringBuilder class"? You mean *instances* of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov from Troelsen book, translated paragraph by me: "If you add more characters than the specified limit, the
StringBuilder object will copy its data to a new instance and increase the buffer size by the specified limit."

Comment: Please EDIT the question with that with the exact quote from original edition  (link or screenshot with copy-pasted quote would be ideal).

Comment: Either that book is wrong or your translation is poor. Increasing the size of a `StringBuilder` beyond its current `Capacity` won't create a new `StringBuilder` object. How could it? You wouldn't have a reference to it afterwards so you couldn't use it. What actually happens is new memory is allocated to store the additional text and that new memory is referenced by the existing `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: Okay, just checked the source code, [it apparently does create new `StringBuilder`s](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs,2414), but it's a very obscure implementation detail, so I'm not sure if *this* is what the book is referring to. Either way, this is not something that you can see by inspecting the IL of your C# code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added original (English) quote

Comment: @Sweeper you should post that as an answer... I found the same quote can be found in Pro C# 7... Agree that this is very confusing way to explain what is going on...

Comment: But Capacity is (quoting the documentation) _"The suggested starting size of the StringBuilder."_. It isn't a definitive limit. As Sweeper says, how it does that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your own C# code's IL will not tell you anything about what `StringBuilder` does *internally*, which is what the book is talking about.  You would need to look at `StringBuilder`'s source code, or its IL to see that.

The documentation of [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0) only mentions "new buffers" or "allocating new memory", and never specifically "new instances of `StringBuilder`".

> New data is appended to the buffer if room is available; otherwise, a new, larger buffer is allocated, data from the original buffer is copied to the new buffer, and the new data is then appended to the new buffer.

> If the number of added characters causes the length of the `StringBuilder` object to exceed its current capacity, new memory is allocated, the value of the `Capacity` property is doubled, new characters are added to the `StringBuilder` object, and its `Length` property is adjusted.

So whether or not it creates new instances of `StringBuilder`s is an implementation detail. Looking at [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/), it does indeed do that in [`ExpandByABlock`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs,2387).

```
// Allocate the array before updating any state to avoid leaving inconsistent state behind in case of out of memory exception
char[] chunkChars = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<char>(newBlockLength);

// Move all of the data from this chunk to a new one, via a few O(1) reference adjustments.
// Then, have this chunk point to the new one as its predecessor.
m_ChunkPrevious = new StringBuilder(this);
m_ChunkOffset += m_ChunkLength;
m_ChunkLength = 0;

m_ChunkChars = chunkChars;
```

In this implementation, `StringBuilder` is implemented as a linked list. The `StringBuilder` instances are nodes. The above code basically sets the previous node to a copy of `this`, and make `this` an "empty" node with a capacity of `newBlockLength`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Am I right the phrase could be changed in a more precise way to not confuse very beginners like me? Other than that the book is great

Comment: @HumbleNewbie Assuming it actually is referring to this implementation detail, I think it shouldn't mention it at all. Knowing this isn't useful in almost all cases. Alternatively, it could say something similar to the wording in the documentation.

Comment: @HumbleNewbie Though you seemed to be confused by a separate issue, that you can somehow observe the internal workings of `StringBuilder` by inspecting your own code's IL. That isn't really the book's fault...

Comment: This is fascinating to me because I never realized that `StringBuilder` is actually implemented as a linked list and I never would have expected it.  It makes a lot more sense now why there are so many advantages to the internal `ValueStringBuilder` type...not the least of which is that it doesn't need to track `StringBuilder` node references.